# Making interactive Angular google chart directive for integrating bubble chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am trying to make interactive google chart(bubble chart) using angular-google-chart directive version 0.1.0.

The Chart rendering is working smoothly until I want to trigger an external event on click of any bubble in chart.

My Html

```
<div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="{{cssStyle}}" custom-select="handleSelect"></div>
```

JS

```
 $scope.handleSelect=function(selection){
                console.log(selection);
            };

            $scope.chartObject = {};
            $scope.chartObject.type = "BubbleChart";
            $scope.chartObject.displayed = true;
            $scope.chartObject.data = {
                                    "cols": [{
                                        "id": "xx",
                                        "label": "xx",
                                        "type": "xx",
                                        "p": {}
                                    }, {
                                        "id": "xx",
                                        "label": "xx",
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "p": {}
                                    }, {
                                        "id": "xx",
                                        "label": "xxx",
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "p": {}
                                    }, {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "label": "",
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "p": {}
                                    }],
                                    "rows": $scope.data
                                };
                $scope.chartObject.options = {
                                            "chartArea": {
                                                top: 10,
                                                bottom: 0,
                                                width: '82%',
                                                height: '85%'
                                            },
                                            "isStacked": "false",
                                            "height": 280,
                                            "fill": 1,
                                            "displayExactValues": true,
                                            "colorAxis": {
                                                minValue: 0,
                                                colors: ['#ff0000', '#ff5300', '#ff8900', '#ffb800', '#ffd600', '#ffe800', '#beee07', '#8edc0c', '#58ce34', '#22ac19']
                                            },
                                            "vAxis": {
                                                "title": "Support Level",
                                                "minValue": 0,
                                                "maxValue": $scope.yaxis_value,
                                                "viewWindowMode": "pretty",
                                                "gridlines": {
                                                    "count": 5
                                                },
                                                "gridlines.color": "#D3D3D3"
                                            },

                                            "hAxis": {
                                                "title": "No. Of Incident",
                                                "maxValue": $scope.xaxis_value,
                                                "gridlines": {
                                                    "count": 4
                                                },
                                                "gridlines.color": "#D3D3D3"
                                            },
                                        };
                $scope.chartObject.formatters = {};
            });
```

My Problem is when I am clicking any bubble chart how to get the exact row value or value that I am passing through chart.

Reference Link I have used:
    http://embed.plnkr.co/lOXTg5XRggwdctUedvfl/preview

But it is still not giving me correct value especially on consecutive clicking of bubble.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any evidence that  `ng-google-chart.js` library contains any issues with selection implementation.

The following example demonstrates how to get the selected value:

```
  $scope.seriesSelected = function (selectedItem) {

      var chartData = $scope.myChart.data;
      var value = chartData.rows[selectedItem.row].c[selectedItem.column].v; //value
      var formattedValue = chartData.rows[selectedItem.row].c[selectedItem.column].f; //formatted value
      console.log(value + ":" + formattedValue);
  };
```

[**Demo (Codepen)**](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/rxdWyE)

From another hand, i have to mention that you are using **not the latest** version of [`angular-google-chart` library](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart).

Since  there are some changes have been made, the following example demonstrates how to bind `select` event **in the latest version**:

```
<div google-chart chart="myChart" agc-on-select="seriesSelected(selectedItem)"></div>
```

[**Demo (Codepen)**](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/YwaprZ)

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I took your suggested code and added some added logic and my issue got resolved. Will put my code in here

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences in the definition of the `div` from the example link and the question...

From the link...

```
<div google-chart chart="myChart" on-select="seriesSelected(selectedItem)">
</div>
```

From the question (without the style attr)...

```
<div google-chart chart="chartObject" custom-select="handleSelect">
</div>
```

Why the `custom-select`? Try defining like this?

```
<div google-chart chart="chartObject" on-select="handleSelect(selection)">
</div>
```

Comment: nothing in the console? are you able to get a working example of your code similar to the link you provided?

Comment: Yup
http://jsfiddle.net/s911131/sjh4wfe2/5/

But here its returning me just row and column number and that too its not regular see selected item and selected items in console.